# Cancelling an alarm set previously

Tags: android, alarm

I'm making an application in which I have implemented a reminder using AlarmManager. Now, if the user wants to cancel this alarm, how can I do the same? 
Also, once the application has asked for alarm services(using alarm manager) and set an alarm, then can we get the details of the alarm we set?

Answer (score 0):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Yes, you can cancel the alarm.  Make sure you're using the same PendingIntent you used when creating the alarm.

What details are you looking for?  Perhaps its best to store these using SharedPreferences.